# Как лучше сделать?

Tags: unity3d

Есть главное меню игры, в нем можно перейти в разные отделу по типу: выбор режима, настройки, магазин и т.п. . Как лучше сделать переключение между ними, сделать разные Canvas на каждое окошко и включать/выключать их в зависимости что открыто или по другому?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае, если это интерактивный элемент, то менее затратным будет в Canvas создать панели(Panel), переименовать, стилизовать под игру, наполнить содержимым( текст, кнопка, изображение) и, как вы описали, включать/выключать в зависимости что открыто.

Comment: Да, так лучше, спасибо

Comment: "менее затратным" только по потраченному времени. Однако ресурсов будет кушать больше, пропорционально кол-ву элементов.
Более оптимальный, на мой взгляд, способ - каждая панель раздела - префаб (сохраненный в папке Resources\(Возможно еще какой-нибудь каталог)). И при нажатии на кнопку раздела - по имени префаба инстанцируется нужная панель. Главное, не использовать ссылки на эти префабы, иначе оптимизации не будет - при загрузке скрипта будут загружены в память префабы, на которые добавленны ссылки

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский обычно загружают все меню сразу, иначе постоянные подгрузки быстро выведут пользователя из себя :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker меню загружается все сразу, вопрос как лучше сделать чтоб одни элементы показывались, а другие нет. Раз с Panel вариант не лучший, можете тогда подсказать как будет лучше?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский  а как лучше сделать, меню загружаться все, надо просто часть скрывать, часть показывать, кроме варианта импортировать все объекты и под отдельности их отключать придумать не могу

Comment: @NeulovimFox я не говорил, что подход с панелями плохой, я даже не ответ прокомментировал, а комментарий другого человека :)